# UPDATE desde una consulta con condiciones

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

con esta query:

```
SELECT id AS wrcId, st AS wrcSt, detail AS wrcDetail,
    CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS ordenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0 AND id IN(
SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30)
ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;
```

obtengo estos resultados (89 lineas en total),

```
| id   |  st |              detail               | OrdenId  |
|:----:|:---:|:---------------------------------:|:--------:|
| 4273 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5117 (Traje Baño) | 5117     |
| 4272 | 16  | Sale invoice # 5116 (Traje Baño)  | 5116     |
| 4270 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5115 (Outlet)     | 5115     |
| 4271 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5114 (Traje Baño) | 5114     |
| ...  | ... | ...                               | ...      |
| ...  | ... | ...                               | ...      |
```

#### Necesito

hacer un UPDATE al campo **st** de la tabla warehouse_rc donde la consulta de mas arriba me da el **id** basado en el OrdenId que son 2 tablas diferentes.

espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Trataste de colocar en el `WHERE` de tu `UPDATE` la query que nos indicas?

Answer (score 0):

@PauloUrbanoRivera, claro, pero obtuve como respuesta

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'warehouse_rc' for update in FROM clause
```

```
UPDATE box_12.warehouse_rc SET st = 0
WHERE(SELECT 
    CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS ordenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE id IN(
    SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30)
);
```